# SSRS and Item-Level Permissions

Tags: list, permissions, reporting-services

Simple and straight question:  Will users that access the SSRS reports I have connected to my SharePoint list inherit the permissions set for that list, including item-level permissions?

Comment: I believe that will depend on how the data source is defined, if you are passing the user along, it should respect item level permissions and show them only the visible items they can see. If you are using a service account or a super reader type account, then they might see something they shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PirateEric's comment is correct. Though, it's not that SSRS respects item level permissions, as SSRS is just making calls like any other app. So it's entirely the responsibility of SharePoint to implement permissions. If SSRS makes the call as a user with access to everything, then the report will have everything. If SSRS makes the call as the current user, then the report will only have the items that the current user has access to.

Comment: Excellent!  thank you!  and thank you too @PirateEric